# Why is Linux signal always handled by main thread?

Tags: linux, multithreading, signals, posix

I use pthread_create to get 2 threads and register the signal handler in both created thread.

**In main thread, the signal handler is not set.**

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void sig_hand(int no)                  //signal handler
{
    printf("handler executing...\n");
    printf("%d\n", pthread_self());
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void* thread1(void *arg1)              //thread1
{
    signal(SIGINT, sig_hand);
    printf("%d\n", pthread_self());
}

void * thread2(void * arg2)           //thread2
{
    signal(SIGINT , sig_hand);
    printf("%d\n", pthread_self());
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t t1;
    pthread_t t2;
    sigset_t newmask;
    sigaddset(&newmask, SIGINT);
    // set sigproc, SIGINT can be received; 
    // sigproc not set, SIGINT can't be received
    if(sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, NULL) < 0){
        perror("sigprocmask error");
    }
    printf("main thread %d\n", pthread_self());
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, thread1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, thread2, NULL);
    while(1);
}
```

If I don't set sigprocmask in main thread, SIGINT can be received, but it is handled by the main thread while main thread doesn't register handler function.

```
main thread -1335200000
-1343535360
-1351928064
^Cpthread -1335200000 handler executing...
```

However if sigprocmask is set in the main thread, SIGINT can't be received while two child threads have registerd handler function.

```
main thread 2061661952
2053326592
2044933888
^C^C
```

This is very confusing.

Comment: Sad! I'm just getting more and more confused.

Comment: See https://devarea.com/linux-handling-signals-in-a-multithreaded-application